# Need help identifying this transformer

Tags: transformer, identification

I recently desoldered this transformer from a circuit board I found, and I need help identifying it. Do the numbers have anything to do with it?

[image]

Comment: You might edit your question to say what the purpose of the circuit is, make / country of origin, pin spacing, etc.

Comment: Something this small is unlikely to be for mains power, so my guess would be an audio transformer. Try putting an audio sine wave (e.g. 1 kHz) in one side, and see what comes out of the other side. That'll tell you the turns ratio, and if you find a similar-looking part, with similar turns ratio and resistance, you'll probably be in luck.

Comment: @jayben Audio transformer, or possibly an SMPS transformer.

Comment: how many pins does it have? ... might not he a transformer

Comment: Most probably custom. You can measure the core, measure or guesstimate the number of turns and perhaps use it for something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Often this is custom transformer and the code is an Internal Customer Code, related to his BOM.
A saw similar transformers in old Servo Drive.